# Why in Zend v1 Zend_Controller not call Global var

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller

Why I can't call global var from the action of Zend_controller?

My code:

```php
require_once 'config.ini.php';
print_r($dbConfig); // in this line work OK

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        //$this->_redirect("index/add");
        global $dbConfig;

        header("Location:index/add");
        print_r($_GLOBAL);// in this line var is undefined, but if I call wrong name of var like $dbConfig1 - I see error.
```

Maby Zend - block global vars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `$GLOBALS`, not `$GLOBAL`.
2. Controller class is not included in global scope, it is included in `Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard::dispatch`. So variables from `config.ini.php` are not available in global scope.
3. Define this variable in `init`

   ```
   public function init()
   {
       require_once 'config.ini.php';
       $this->dbConfig = $dbConfig;
   }

   public function indexAction()
   {
       print_r($this->dbConfig);
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: No, It's not work to. So I do it in view and not work too. Why)?

Comment: http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Allowing-global-variables-with-Zend-Framework-td643899.html    - this man talk too about

Comment: Ups, thanks You are right! I didn't see that I use require_once in 2 points. So after use directive requed - it's work. Thanks!!!

Comment: you can use `require` instead of `require_once` to make multiple includes

Comment: But its very strange, If a have 3 classes i neen 3 require....  So ... I cant use require_once... Is it normal for zend?

Comment: Zend Framework has nothing with `require` and `require_once`

Comment: The require_once statement is identical to require except PHP will check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include (require) it again. http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php, http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Comment: In my case, ini file with global vars include in my auth-class in begin of file. But then class is constructed global vars is gone, and i repite requied ini file in constructor. So if I use requide_once system not repite load ini file... Very strange situation... in my experience of zend

Comment: Try to use action helper to have only one copy of config

Comment: In finally - I include global vars in index.php - and All works OK!